# iText7 - how to keep pre-existing content in PDF when calling Document.relayout()

Tags: java, itext7

Dears,

Using iText7 to generate PDF document,
We would like to use the low level API (Kernel/Canvas) first to draw the CoverPage, then use the HighLevel API (Document) to add textual content.
To generate a TOC page after the CoverPage the Document has its immediateFlush attribute set to false, to insert the TOC and then call Document.relayout().

Unfortunately Document.relayout() removes all existing pages, then rerender the document, the problem is that our CoverPage removed as well.

see: [com.itextpdf.layout.Document#relayout line 196](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/44c5b1f5436a306c7185caa81e63f41c86ca0c33/layout/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/layout/Document.java#L196):

```
    while (pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages() > 0) {
        pdfDocument.removePage(pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages());
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: As a workaround I extend class Document to override method `relayout()` with the same code without the offending lines, works perfectly, though it may not be the ideal answer to my question...

Comment: Could you share a minimal code example?